# sql query to get earliest date for different people

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select the earliest date that a user could in either 3 places from a table.

```
SELECT RecordID,  
    (
        SELECT MIN(dDate) 
        FROM (
            VALUES(DateSent), 
            (DiaryDate),                 
            (CareDate)
        ) As EarliestDate(dDate)
    ) AS dDate 
FROM tblOrderDetails 
WHERE Flagged = 0 
AND SalesID= '" & UserID & "'
OR Flagged = 0 
And RepID= '" & UserID & "' 
OR Flagged = 0 
AND CareID= '" & UserID & "'"
```

Comment: What's the problem? What is your DB structure? I think you need to wrap each `some AND some` with `()` to work along with `() OR () OR ()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you are attempting to do.  If I'm understanding correctly, you want the min date for those three columns for the given RecordID.  You can do that by doing a UNION ALL each RecordID with each column. This can be subqueried to get the MIN(date).  AS Justinas pointed out, you have a problem in your WHERE, and have to be careful mixing ANDs and ORs.

```
SELECT dT.RecordID, MIN(dT.inDate) AS [EarliestDate]
  FROM (
          SELECT RecordID, DateSent AS [inDate]
            FROM tblOrderDetails
           WHERE Flagged = 0 
             AND (   SalesID= '" & UserID & "'
                  OR   RepID= '" & UserID & "' 
                  OR  CareID= '" & UserID & "'
                 )

          UNION ALL

          SELECT RecordID, DiaryDate AS [inDate]
            FROM tblOrderDetails
           WHERE Flagged = 0 
             AND (   SalesID= '" & UserID & "'
                  OR   RepID= '" & UserID & "' 
                  OR  CareID= '" & UserID & "'
                 )

          UNION ALL

          SELECT RecordID, CareDate AS [inDate]
            FROM tblOrderDetails
           WHERE Flagged = 0 
             AND (   SalesID= '" & UserID & "'
                  OR   RepID= '" & UserID & "' 
                  OR  CareID= '" & UserID & "'
                 )
       ) AS dT
GROUP BY RecordID
```

Comment: This produces the right result, it doesn't include high dates that are belonging to different people's ID.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the *earliest* date, you want `MIN()`.  The following will work in some databases:

```
SELECT od.RecordID,  
       (SELECT MIN(EarliestDate.dDate) 
        FROM (VALUES (od.DateSent), (od.DiaryDate), (od.CareDate)
             ) As EarliestDate(dDate)
       ) as dDate 
FROM tblOrderDetails od 
WHERE (od.Flagged = 0 AND od.SalesID = '" & UserID & "') OR
      (od.Flagged = 0 AND od.RepID= '" & UserID & "') OR 
      (od.Flagged = 0 AND od.CareID= '" & UserID & "'");
```

(Assuming this is the logic you want, you do not need parentheses in your query.)

The `WHERE` clause can be simplified to:

```
WHERE od.Flagged = 0 AND ? IN (od.SalesId, od.RepId, od.CareId)
```

Note that `?` is a place holder for a parameter. You should be passing values in as a *parameter*, not munging the query string.

EDIT:

This would often be written using a `CASE` as Noxtrhon suggests.  The simplest version -- assuming no `NULL` values -- would be:

```
SELECT od.RecordID, 
       (CASE WHEN od.DateSent <= od.DiaryDate and od.DateSent <= od.CareDate
             THEN ad.DateSent
             WHEN od.DiaryDate <= od.CareDate
             THEN od.DiaryDate
             ELSE od.CareDate
        END) as dDate 
FROM tblOrderDetails od 
WHERE (od.Flagged = 0 AND od.SalesID = '" & UserID & "') OR
      (od.Flagged = 0 AND od.RepID= '" & UserID & "') OR 
      (od.Flagged = 0 AND od.CareID= '" & UserID & "'");
```

If I recall correctly, the `CASE` should have slightly better performance, but the improvement is much less than I would expect.

Comment: I wish SQL server had `LEAST` function

Comment: Still getting 0101000 0000 for this. Zero time i think.

Answer (score 0):

you can use case statement to check the cases and decide which one to select. you have asked for the earliest date but you are selecting latest date as Max(...) in your query, this query returns the earliest one:

```
SELECT RecordID, 
 case when DateSent < DiaryDate and DateSent < CareDate then DateSend
      when DiaryDate < DateSent and DiaryDate < CareDate then DiaryDate
      else CareDate end as dDate
FROM tblOrderDetails
WHERE Flagged = 0 AND
      SalesID = '" & UserID & "'OR Flagged = 0 And
      RepID = '" & UserID & "' OR Flagged = 0 AND CareID= '" & UserID & "'"
```

Comment: I don't know why this would be downvoted.   A `CASE` is the "natural" way to answer the question -- although this case is not quite optimal.